# How come I get no output from this piece of code?

Tags: c#

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Timers;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Timer time = new Timer();
                    time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(action);
                    time.Interval = 5000;
                    time.Enabled = true;

                    time.Start();


                }

                static void action(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("haha\n");
                }

            }
        }
```

This piece of code doesnt have any output. Could anyone tell me what the problem is? Thank you very much. I followed exact code on MSDN.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I used ctrl+F5. No output

Comment: while (true){} after time.Start(); will keep it looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer goes out of scope immediately and thus is never called. The program exits before it has a chance to fire the action.

You can make your main method sleep by adding this after `time.start()`:

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
Thread.Sleep(interval);
```

Comment: How much seconds will it wait?

Comment: Using thread requires me to add thread class, but I am using system timer.

Comment: TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval);

Comment: It doesn't have any effect. Still no output.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {

        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(action);
        time.Interval = 100;
        time.Enabled = true;

        time.Start();
        string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
        if (line == "exit") // Check for exit condition
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("End of Program\n");

}

static void action(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("haha\n");
}

}
```